# Difference between android.support.content vs android.content

Tags: android

Iam an android beginner. I couldn't understand when we have to use imports statements starting with android.support.content and android.content? 
I used content as an example.

Comment: One is from the support library, the other is not

Comment: You use the support library when you are using relatively new features in your app while you app is targeting devices with lower API levels. For example, `android.widget.Toolbar` was introduced in API level 21, so if you want to use a `Toolbar` while your app has `minSdkVersion` lower than 21 (down to 7), you should use `android.support.v7.widget.toolbar` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Support Library is generally used when you want to easily support a wider range of OS versions with less version specific source - with it you can use features introduced in higher version of the OS on older platforms without having to worry and check whether this platform has that feature and do something in case it doesn't.

For more information: it has already been discussed and this was a part of the answer, there are many more and they are useful so read them if you want to know in depth how,why and when. Hope this helps. [Support library android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23345925/when-to-use-support-library)

Comment: Thanks for the info